# `adb devices` (not showing emulators) versus `emulator -list-avds` (returns emulators)

Tags: android, android-emulator

What's the difference between listing your virtual devices with `adb devices` versus `emulator -list-avds`? For some reason my Android Virtual Device (AVD) isn't playing nice.

When I run adb devices (`/Users/gui/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb devices`) the return is empty. However emulator -list-avds (`/Users/gui/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator -list-avds`) it lists my emulators:

`Nexus_5X_API_26_test
Nexus_5X_API_26_x86
Nexus_5X_API_27_x86`

Answer (score 2):

`adb devices` lists *running* emulators and attached debuggable devices. `emulator -list-avds` lists *defined* emulator images, regardless of whether there is an emulator running or not using any of those images.